# Do keybindings exist in Pharo3?

Tags: pharo

Is it possible, in a supported fashion, to change keybindings in Pharo3? For example I'd like do have the basic emacs keys (C-e, C-a, etc) when I'm in a Workspace or editing code.

Comment: I don't know if something changes in 3.0, but here is a guide for 2.0 http://playingwithobjects.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/keymappings-101-for-pharo-2-0/

Answer (score 4):

Keybindings in Pharo3 should be working without problem, as in 2.0.

Now... it is a good package, but not as powerful as you would want to make your package bindings *alla emacs*. There has been some efforts to do that, but there is some VM support missing (Since Pharo4 will be oriented to improve tools, you can expect this situation change in the future, but not immediatly).